# How to combine three integers from three sequences such that all the numbers in the triplet be coprime.

Tags: prime-numbers, combinations

So there are three sequences of integers denoted $s_1, s_2$ and $s_3$. Each of them starts at $2$ and goes up to an integer $N$. In other words, they're all identical sequences of numbers of the form $\{2,\dots,N\}$.

The question is as such:

Is there a way to make triplets of numbers $\{a,b,c\} \forall (a \in s_1, b \in s_2,c \in s_3) $ such that every number in a triplet is coprime to the other two and no number of any of the three sequences is left out of a triplet, or show up in more than one of them?

Comment: You're right, that was a gaffe, sorry. I corrected the sequences to start at $2$ instead of $0$.

Comment: I'd like some clarification: would this be a valid set of sequences? $s_1 =\{2, 3, 4, 5\}$, $s_2 = s_3 = s_1$?

Comment: That's is exactly it. All of the three sequences are equal.

Answer (score 1):

With the sequences starting at $2$, no.  There are too many even numbers around.  Two of them will wind up in the same triplet.  If you start at $1$ you can succeed with $N=1,3$ but not otherwise.

Comment: So if I start at $1$, I can succeed if I have odd numbers of elements? Or I can only succeed if I only have odd numbers in my sequence?

Comment: If you start and end at $1$, you can have the trivial $\{1,1,1\}$.  If you start and end at $3$, you can have $\{1,2,3\}$ three times.  If you start at $1$ and go to $4$ or more you have too many evens-at least one of the triplets will have two evens.    If $N=4$, you have six even numbers to put in five triplets.  If you use only odds, you probably can do it, because the density of multiples of $3$ is $1/3$ so you can put one in each triplet.